# Get array of elements from a string and look up values

Tags: javascript, arrays, lookup, indexof

I have a calculation string from a database like:

```
var calc = "{a}+{b}==2"
```

and I want to pull all the elements with "{}" so that I can look up their values from a database. What's the **fastest** way of doing this, so I end up with an ordered array that I can look up, and replace the values back in the string.

I've considered:

```
 - For loop, looking for { then finding the next }
 - Split with a map
 - IndexOf
```

Comment: Replace should work, if I've understood correctly. Use regex to find each of those variables, and replace with the value.

Comment: How about using regex?

Comment: Thanks, I know there's a lot of options. I was hoping for an example of the most efficent/fastest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex

```
 var exp = /{([^}]+)}/g ,index;
  while(index = exp.exec("{a}+{b}==2")) {
    console.log(index[1]);
  }
```

.
[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/b7be0wnf/)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's the "fastest" way, but you should consider using a regex.

Something like:

```
var calc = "{a}+{b}==2";
var re = /{([^}]+)}/g;
var res;
var result = [];
while (res = re.exec(calc))
{
    result.push(res[1]);
}
console.log(result);
```

Your regex may need to be refined based on the actual definition of the {} expressions (based on allowed characters, quoting, etc.).

Once you have received the values back, you can then use `replace` to replace the values.

```
var values = {a: 1, b: 3};
var replaced = calc.replace(re,function(match,name) { return values[name]; });
console.log(replaced);
```

NB: be **very** careful if you plan to then send this to `eval` or the like.

Comment: I do plan to send them to eval - can you clarify when you say be careful?

Comment: If you are not 100% certain of the contents of the string you're going to evaluate, then don't use `eval`. Remember `eval` will execute anything you throw at it. It could be used for XSS, CSRF... Search for "eval dangerous".

Answer (score 0):

Regex comes to the mind first but one other way of implementing this job in O(n) time could be;

```js
function getDatas(s){
  var dataOn = false;
  return Array.prototype.reduce.call(s,(d,c) => dataOn ? c !== "}" ? (d[d.length-1] += c,d)
                                                                   : (dataOn = false, d)
                                                       : c === "{" ? (dataOn = true, d.push(""),d)
                                                                   : d, []);
  
}

var calc = "{a}+{b}+{colorSpace}==2",
  result = getDatas(calc);
console.log(result);
```

So out of curiosity i have done some tests on [JSBen](http://jsben.ch/#/uoZb6) and it seems that @jcaron's regex is indeed much efficient. You may extend those tests with any of your other ideas like `indexOf` or `for` loop.